# What is the significance "Development Mode" on User Record details?

Tags: profile, user-record, admin, development-mode, user-profile

I can see a "Development Mode" flag for the User-Records under System Administrator profile and not able to see in other Profiles.

I am using the DEV ORG. Can someone tell me the significance of this Flag and its impact on the system based if its selected or not selected?

[image]

Comment: i do not get questions like this when the feature is well documented: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_tools_edit_toolbar.htm. Can you rephrase the question to narrow it to what you do not understand? It takes much less time to read the docs than to wait for an answer

Comment: The topic may be well documented  but what really is missing in the documents are the screenshots! (images speak a lot).

Comment: @Eric I checked couple of links similar to the one you shared. Since I am very new to this and no work experience in Salesforce I got little confused about the usage of this after referring all the links. As mentioned by sdfcFanBoy & Martin the screenshots helped me to resolve my query & further confusion. Thanks all for your help

Comment: For future reference a good question would have been a question about those confusions. Not a blanket "what is it"

Comment: @Eric .. Noted & Sure will do in future

Comment: @sfdcfanboy -cause that screen is not available to anyone?? That's why we have DE orgs, to play and learn. Just saying a question like this is too broad and the docs answer it (on its face) well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With development mode enabled, you will be able to edit visualforce page and classes right in the browser, without using developer console.  Below every Visualforce page, you get a new section (which can be minimized) to edit it as shown below.

[image]

You can also see the "view state" of the visualforce page.

Comment: So this is only for Admin profiles only?

Answer (score 0):

It adds a section to the bottom of visualforce pages where you can edit the visualforce markup and the page controller.

[image]

Comment: @Robertthomas Yes, I believe that this is only for Admin profiles.